# Very simple proof help about integers

Tags: proof-writing

I was wondering if anybody could help me with proving something very simple: that $9n\ne6$ when n is any integer. It seems extremely intuitive but I don't know how to make it into part of a rigorous proof.

Comment: Take $n=0$ and $n=1$...?

Comment: It's useful to prove the contrapositive.  Namely, prove that if $9n=6$ for some real number $n$, then $n$ is not an integer.  The contrapositive is logically equivalent to the statement you're trying to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$9n=6$ so $n=6/9=2/3$ which is not an integer.

Alternatively you might say $9=3^2$ and $6=2\cdot 3$ and the result follows from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: oh my gosh I can't believe that I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: This shows that $\,9n = 6\,\Rightarrow\,3n = 2.\ \ $ That the latter has no integer solution $\,n\,$ still requires *proof*.

Comment: If $3n=2$ then it follows from the FT of arithmetic that $3|2$. Done.

Answer (score 1):

If $9n=6$ then we consider two cases for n:

1) n is odd. Then 9n is odd too. But $2|6$. A contradiction. Therefore $9n\neq 6$.

2) n is even. Let $n=2k$ for some integer k. So $9\times 2k =6$ or $3k=1$. In the latter, 3 divides the LHS but does not divide RHS. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $n$ is an integer, then either $n\geq 1$ or $n \leq 0$. Would either case allow $9n = 6$?